# PERL - DBD::mysql::st execute failed: MySQL client ran out of memory

Tags: mysql, perl

I've researched a bit and found that using `mysql_use_result=1` is supposed to alleviate the memory issue.  However, since I am new to this `DBI module` I don't understand what is happening here:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

use strict;
use DBI;


my $dbh = DBI>connect('DBI:mysql:blah;host=blah.blah.blah.blah;mysql_use_result=1','blah','blah',{RaiseError => 1});

my $sth = $dbh->prepare('select * from TaqMinute where tradeDate<=\'2014-04-22\' and symbol<=\'AAPL\' ;') ;

if (defined($sth)) {
        $sth->execute();
    my @row;
    while (@row = $sth-> fetchrow_array()) {
       print "@row\n" ;
    }
}
$sth->finish();


$dbh->disconnect
```

Before I added `mysql_use_result=1`, the script would fail after about 1.5 minutes complaining that it ran out of memory.  After adding this my query arguments are ignored and I simply get all the data in the database.

Any ideas how to help me or how to use this `switch` properly?  Btw, the database that I am querying is very large.

Thanks in advance!

Craig

Comment: You should move the `$sth->finish();` inside the `if` block because otherwise if `$sth` is undef, you'll still try to call `->finish` against it.

Comment: If you're getting all the data in the table, then your query is matching every row, and `mysql_use_result` is delivering the result set without storing it in memory.  Which is to say, why do you think you shouldn't be getting all the rows?  Can you demonstrate that conclusively?

Comment: I'm not saying that I shouldn't be getting all the rows, I'm simply stating that when storing the data I run out of memory and the only solution I could find for this error message was to use  mysql_use_result which IMO is the same as simply using select * without any arguments.  I could be wrong, but this is my observation.  Again, I am unfamiliar with the uses of the module and still learning about it.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use parametized queries, maybe something wrong with your qoutes.

```
my $dbh = DBI>connect('DBI:mysql:blah;host=blah.blah.blah.blah','blah','blah',{RaiseError => 1});
my $sth = $dbh->prepare_cached('select * from TaqMinute where tradeDate<=? and symbol<=?') ;
die "sth undef!" if ! defined $sth;
$sth->execute('2014-04-22','AAPL');
while (my $rowref = $sth->fetchrow_arrayref()) {
 print Dumper($rowref) ;
}
$sth->finish;
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I will incorporate that into my scripts going forward, however I still get the memory error even with your recommendation.

Comment: You could try to use fetchrow_arrayref, it is a bit more efficient. You could try to 64 bit perl if nothing else works. I am just curious: how many rows and columns is in your table? Could use only one column? What type of fields do you have?

Comment: AFAIK, there are approximately 2000 stocks, 390 rows/day/stock (one minute increments over 6.5 hours), 252 days/year, 10 years, 28 columns... ~55,036,800,000 unique elements.  ~1,965,600,000 rows. The output of your new code does not resolve the specific parameters that I desire; it outputs every row available. $VAR1 = [ 'AAII',      '2004-02-26','330','4','15.5400','15.5300','15.5400',         '15.5375','31075','2000','8','15.5300','15.5400','600','700',        '2','15.5400','15.5400','15.5400','15.5400','23310','1500',         '2','15.5300','15.5400','600','700',''];

Comment: I was able to get things going.  It was my error in the MySQL syntax.  Thank you all for your help.